# Wordpress: How does a plugin generate a page?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, query-variables

Could someone please solve a beginner's crisis for me? I simply CANNOT figure out how a plugin generates a page or even multiple pages *without making a page template in the dashboard*. I have read Google results and even talked to the author of this plugin I am reading through to get an idea but the way he explained it was too complex for me to understand. [Here is a link in case you want to see his explanation](https://anspress.io/questions/question/how-is-the-ask-question-page-displayed/?show_answer=9390&ap_notification_read=202975#answer_9390). But I just want to understand...If a plugin is **ONE** PHP script, then whatever function calls the HTML template for the page must `include()` it right? At least that's how this plugin does it. But then why is it that when I click on one of the pages for the plugin I see this in the URL: http://www.efficientmind.org/?page_id=73. What does the ?page_id=73 mean? And how does `query_vars` play a part in all this? I'm so confused...Could someone maybe explain it in layman's terms and then also in a more technical so I can compare and contrast??

Comment: Your question should be "how to create wordpress page automatically" the answer is to simply use [wp_insert post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: @silver I got that part but I guess I'm more interested in how 1 shortcode on a page can have many "pages" within it. The plugin I am extending is called [Anspress](www.anspress.io) and it uses 1 shortcode to use the entire plugin. I'm trying to understand how the author achieved this effect.

Comment: Dig on the plugin file and look for the line that says ```add_shortcode('anspress' , ...``` and all the functions connected to it, I'm not sure if someone would be able to properly explain you about the plugin was constructed its structure and how it executes except the author or someone who would dig and read the plugin files

Comment: also, try reading wordpress docs regarding about some of your question, like what is [Wordpress Query Var](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars), I don't think you can easily understand the plugin structure unless you are familiar with wordpress API, functions, Classes, hooks, filters etc.

Comment: @silver I try to read the Codex but sometimes it is so dry and hard to follow, especially for a beginner like me. I have skipper around on the Wordpress Query Var page but because most of it doesn't make sense yet I don't feel like I've learned anything. But I'll give it another go, thanks mate.

Comment: We've always been there, just do it over and over again.